# Unable to install vim editor on Ubuntu 17.04 even after doing sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

My sources.list file is as follows :

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
```

Upon doing sudo-get update , I get the following result at the end :

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security            Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Upon doing sudo apt-get install vim I get the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate

W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: IIRC 17.04 is near the end of its life-cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is that 17.04 reached end of life... So you need to change the repositorys to old-releases. Please backup your sources.list and replace the content with

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

then try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` after that. Now you should be good to go to install vim. I didn't try it. Found solution at: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382832

Comment: thanx bro....that worked perfectly :-)